# New to using API - Can the Wikia API provide deep data such as tables cells?

Tags: api, wikia

I've just found out Wikia has an API, I know the basics about using API and I'd like to perform requests to collect data from specific cells from specific pages on http://clashroyale.wikia.com/api/v1

Sadly, browsing the list of endpoints, I'm not sure whether I can get specific data such as some values from a table (example : data from the table at the bottom of the page http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Hog_Rider).

Am I doing it wrong, or are these data not available from the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the raw content of the page with Wikia's API, there is no safe way to retrieve the data contained in this table.